# Error al Instalar SQLSERVER 2017

Tags: sql, instalacion

He intentado varias veces instalar sql server de distintas versiones pero siempre recibo este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si es desde un disco es probable que este rayado o mal copiado.... si tienes los archivos, entonces intenta descargarlo de nuevo, lo mas probable es que los archivos estén dañados....

Comment: Ok gracias, voy a intentarlo